# How to capture packets and put them into a database in real time?

Tags: packet-capture

I have a project on DNS reflection prevention and I need somehow to capture incoming and outgoing packets in real time... I am working on Linux Debian 8.0... can you please tell me how to do that... I looked in many websites and watched many tutorials but they were confusing and didn't help at all.. could you please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) for listening for network traffic and capturing the packets. A command-line version - [T-shark](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html) can output structured XML, which you can store into the database using the programming language / tools of your choice.

Comment: You are welcome :) Hint for using StackOverflow: if you consider an answer helpful, you can upvote it by pressing the up arrow to the left of the answer. If you are the original poster (who asked the question), you can also mark the most helpful answer by accepting it with the big tick, also to the left of the answer.